# Putting all records in an array column in Amazon Kinesis Analytics SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I want to use Analytics SQL to combine all windowed values of column in the input stream into an array in the output stream.

Say I have a data coming in that looks like this:

| event | product_id | product_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| page_view | 1111 | 3.99 |
| page_view | 2222 | 10.99 |

The following SQL would give me output that shows for each 30 minute window, how many products were viewed and what the highest price among them was.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM" (
    "event_type" varchar(32),
    "count_products_viewed" integer,
    "max_price_viewed" decimal(7,2)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS 
    INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
        SELECT STREAM 
            "stream_1"."event",
            COUNT("stream_1"."product_id") as "count_products_viewed,
            MAX("stream_1"."product_price") as "max_price_viewed"
        FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001" as "stream_1"
        WINDOWED BY STAGGER (
            PARTITION BY
            "stream_1"."event"
            RANGE INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
        );
```

So the output data would like something like

| event | count_products_viewed | max_price_viewed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| page_view | 2 | 10.99 |

If I wanted to add another column so that it looked like

| event | count_products_viewed | max_price_viewed | list_products_viewed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| page_view | 2 | 10.99 | [1111, 2222] |

What would I need to do? Tried combing through the docs but didn't find anything for working with all of a column's values during a window.

It doesn't need to be a literal array - I'm fine with a json string of the same data.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @stumpbeard , Did you solve this ? I am looking for exactly the same thing .

Comment: I didn't, I ended up having to do this in-app instead of in kinesis. However, it seems like Kinesis Analytics has been updated a lot since I last used it, so maybe it's possible now! Please let me know if you figure it out.